# Enable Microsoft Word Heading Styles in a table

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office, formatting

I have a table with content in it.

I highlighted the content inside one of the table cells and set the Heading Style to Heading 2.

But Word doesn't recognize it when I do a Table Of Contents. Only Heading Styles set outside the table is recognized and inserted in the Table Of Contents.

Comment: It works when I do it - see this [sample document](https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=617286641A7BF596%21786).  Can you provide a sample file where this doesn't work?

Comment: Strangely, now it worked. Thanks, I think it was some other formatting issues just now when I did it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way you can get this done is to:

1. Insert Table of Contents

   [image: insert TOC]
2. Click "Options" Button.
3. Check "Table entry fields" checkbox.

   [image: Options dialogs]
4. Ok. Ok.

**Result:**

[image: Output]

Answer (score 0):

See also: https://wordribbon.tips.net/T010146_Headings_in_Tables_Not_Showing_in_TOC.html

If you find that one heading style is working in the TOC, but you want the table heading to look differently, simply make the table heading the same as an existing heading style, then "Save Selection as a New Quick Style", and modify as needed.